# Assigning Boolean returns Boolean, but assigning integer does not. Why?

Tags: java, integer, boolean

Earlier I have `b=true` in an if condition and it is considered as a Boolean. 
But the same does not apply to an integer. For `x=1` I am getting an error

> Cannot convert from int to boolean.

Below is the code snippet.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = false;
        if (b = true)
            System.out.println("b true");
        else
            System.out.println("b false");

        int x = 0;

        if (x = 1)
            System.out.println("x 1");
        else
            System.out.println("x 0");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `=` and `==`? Are you using `=` intentionally?

Comment: You are not comparing `x` to `1`, you are setting `x = 1`. Add another `=` to make it `if (x == 1)`...

Comment: @Sweeper based on the title of the question, the OP know they are using an assignment operator.

Comment: It is a language design (int not convertable to boolean) to prevent mistakenly using **assignment =** instead of **comparison ==` in an **if** condition. Though a boolean assignment delivers a boolean and hence is permitted. Justifiable as boolean comparison would be an equivalence test.

Comment: @JoopEggen arguably the language decision is to _require_ that the expression in an `if` clause can only accept a boolean.  The assign vs compare is a useful side effect, but any compiler can trivially detect and warn about that these days.

Comment: @Alnitak indeed; I might have sought more intention in the language design of Java here, than there actually was. Can warn, and compile error are two different cases. IMHO an error message hinting at = vs. == would be ideal, perhaps with a repair option in the IDE..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in the Java Language Specification, [section 15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

> At run time, *the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.* The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable.

Assignments are actually expressions. They evaluate to a value as well. What value? The value that is assigned to the variable. So if we ignore the side effect of assignment, your if statements are equivalent to:

```
boolean b = false;
if (true)
    System.out.println("b true");
else
    System.out.println("b false");

int x = 0;

if (1)
    System.out.println("x 1");
else
    System.out.println("x 0");
```

Obviously, `if (1)` is invalid, as only `boolean` values can go in the `()` of an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

`b = true` is an assignment expression whose value is `true`. Therefore it can be used in a condition.

`x = 1` is an assignment expression whose value is `1`. `1` is not `boolean`, and therefore cannot be used in a condition.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is the point of this condition but theoretically you could use following construction:

```
    int x = 0;
    if ((x = 1) == 1)
        System.out.println("x 1");
    else
        System.out.println("x 0");
```

Comment: Was checking out of curiosity. Nothing more. Your template does address the question.

Answer (score 0):

### if (b = true)

run the below code segment if the result *(of assigning value true to b)* is equal to `true`

### if (x = 1)

compilation error because `if()` construct in java ONLY ACCEPTS boolean. But `x = 1` is cannot be evaluated to a boolean. It is evaluated to value 1